# How to apply catalogs to the overriding layout of FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, bundle

as [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) is said I've overrided the layout.html.twig template of
FOSUserBundle.

This is the new template:

```
//app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views
{% extends 'AibFrontendBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content%}
    <div>
        {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
            {{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%':
app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }} |
            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
                {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
            </a>
        {% else %}
            <a
href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">{{ 'layout.login'|
trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    {% for key, message in app.session.getFlashes() %}
    <div class="{{ key }}">
        {{ message|trans({}, 'messages') }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div>
        {% block fos_user_content %}
        {% endblock fos_user_content %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see my layout.html.twig is almost the same as the original
FOSUserBundle, but I'm calling the i18n catalog "messages".

I have messages.it.xliff  inside /Aib/FrontendBundle/Resources/
translations. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext"
original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Bad credentials</source>
                <target>Username o password invalidi</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

The problem: the translation of "Bad credentials" doesn't work..

I cleared the cache.

Comment: In this bundle, translations seem to be in the yml format : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.it.yml Maybe you could try with a yml file... what is weird is I can't find "Bad credentials" in the english translation file : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.yml Are you up-to-date?

Comment: Would you bother answering when someone comments your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to your answer.
creating a yml file here did the trick for me: `app/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.fr.yml`
If you don't know how to fill this file, look for the file with a similar name in the bundle. Clearing the cache is important.

You really pissed me off by not answering my comment on this question (and on several others), but your question is a good question and some other people may need the answer, and there is no reason for them not to get an answer so here it is. Have a good day, and please reply when someone talks to you. It is basic politeness.