# FOSUserBundle , French translation is ignored

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am a new user of symfony  I currently following a course( full time), My problem :

```
# app/config/config.yml

framework:
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
```

app/config/parameters.ini: I set up the French traduction(fr):

```
; These parameters can be imported into other config files
; by enclosing the key with % (like %database_user%)
; Comments start with ';', as in php.ini
[parameters]
    database_driver   = pdo_mysql
    database_host     = localhost
    database_port     =
    database_name     = blog
    database_user     = root
    database_password =

    mailer_transport  = smtp
    mailer_host       = localhost
    mailer_user       =
    mailer_password   =

    locale            = fr

    secret            = ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

but labels forms register / login, is still in English...
I use version `FriendsOfSymfony-FOSUserBundle-1.2.0-0` , because of bug under the latest `FriendsOfSymfony-FOSUserBundle-1.2.0-57-g72e8023`

Any help please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply catalogs to the overriding layout of FOSUserBundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008469/how-to-apply-catalogs-to-the-overriding-layout-of-fosuserbundle)

Comment: Thx greg, I followed the steps but it does not work (also clearing the cache)... I doubted that version is not stable....

Comment: If you can read french, then maybe you should have a look a this : http://www.siteduzero.com/forum-83-773976-p1-symfony2-tuto-faq.html#r7469726

Comment: solved!, the problem is that you must disconnect and reconnect, to get the latest update...(Mes salutations).

Comment: Bien joué! You may answer your own question with that to get some reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After editing the file parameters.ini, it is necessary to:

1. disconnect(if you been logged)
2. reconnect
3. ...
4. reload the
       page(/login)  if it does not work, then clear the Cache and reload

if you plan to customize the translated language , you may to copy/paste the 
`vendor\bundles\FOS\UserBundle\Resources\translations`  in your own Bundle `src\Mysite\UserBundle\Resources\translations` Or under `app\Resources` (don't modify the original traduction!).

Comment: its a shame that symfony2 doesn't reset the session / cookie once the configuration has been changed.