# Symfony twig translation in overrided FOS template

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm in a overrided template of FosUserBundle in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Profile/edit.html.twig`

This is the template :

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="bg-lightBlue fg-white align-center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="no-overflow padding30" style="padding-top: 40px">

                    <h1 class="text-shadow metro-title text-light padding20">
                        {{ 'member.profile'|trans }}
                    </h1>

                    <div class="text-light" style="padding-bottom:30px">
                        {% include "FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit_content.html.twig" %}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see in h1, I have : `{{ 'member.profile'|trans }}`, but the translation does not work in this template.

Translations are working in other views in my bundle, so I think the problem is from FosUser.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It's because you are using the `FOSUserBundle` domain for your translations. Remove`{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}` and it should work as expected.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? What did you expect? What did you get instead? Where did you place the translation for the `member.profile` key?

Comment: perhaps read this - [StackOverflow 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108075/fosuserbundle-french-translation-is-ignored) - [StackOverflow 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008469/how-to-apply-catalogs-to-the-overriding-layout-of-fosuserbundle)

Comment: It doesn't work means in my view, I have member.profile displayed instead of my translation. I know it's FosUser trans the problem, but I need to keep these translations too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use FOSUserBundle translation domain you have to override the fos translation files too to make this work. Other solution is to change the translation domain where te translated message is

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in app/config/config.yml file, in framework section, this line is uncomment: translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }. I had this issue, so I did this and it worked for me.